# Host not allowed to connect to this server in 000webhost

Tags: mysql, web-hosting

## Summary

I've seen from a site where the user mentioned to wait for 1 day before the host take effect. But however after 1 day, I am still getting the error below:

> Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/1130):
>   Host '10.1.1.25' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in
>   /home/a123456/public_html/index.php on line 2

## Detailed explanation

I am a free user and I've created a database in 000webhost but I'm not able to use it after I've completed the setup. I am not connect remotely. I feel that I understood the guide correctly but still not able to get things done. My details are as follow:

- host: mysql5.000webhost.com
- username: a123456_uname
- database name: a123456_dbname
- password: password1

I am using **mysqli** to establish the connection. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("mysql5.000webhost.com", "a123456_uname", "password1", "a123456_dbname");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: check out OpenShift. They have free geers and are very respectable. https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html ... who knows, maybe someday you will punt them a nickel. That is their business model. Btw it is RedHat and AWS (primarily RedHat monetarily, but it is the AWS answer for PaaS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL grants privileges for users to connect but may restrict these connection to certain hosts or network ranges.

By analogy: it's like if I allow a friend to call my phone and get through my telephone blocking, but only if he calls me from his own number.

It's pretty clear from the error you got that the host you're running your PHP script from, 10.1.1.25, is not yet in the range allowed to connect to the MySQL server. Either the hosting company is taking longer than 1 day to configure your permissions (what do you expect as a free user?), or else there has been some miscommunication about which host you're going to run your PHP scripts from.

You should contact your hosting company. They can figure out what's going on in this specific case. Folks here on Stack Overflow cannot.

PS: I really hope you didn't just post your MySQL password on the internet.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. I know what I am doing (no that is not the password), just that I need some clarification on this issue, if it may take 1 week, at least I should be informed, I think that's what I get as a free user XD

Answer (score 0):

There is an instant workaround for this issue. Just replace the host name ("mysql5.000webhost.com") for it's IP address. To know the ip address you may use the "ping" command on DOS. Just open a CMD window and type "ping mysql5.000webhost.com". I.E:

> ping mysql5.000webhost.com

Pinging mysql5.000webhost.com [10.1.1.105] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 10.1.1.105:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

>

In this case the IP is: 10.1.1.105.
Just replace it and it will work.